# Запретить появление блока

Tags: php, html, текст

.Здравствуйте. Вообщем появилась такая проблемка, нужно убрать появление блока после bodу. Реклама появляется от хостинга и поэтому у этого div нету класса, так бы я и сам смог скрыть. Помогите друзья!) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте селектор `body>div:first-child`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Очень благодарен, блок удалось скрыть!!

Comment: могу оформить как ответ =)

Comment: ок, галочку хотите?)

Comment: ну не помешает, а еще может кому-то еще поможет, т.к. то что читают комментарии шансов меньше, особенно те кто пришел из поисковика

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: нет проблем, оращайтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам подойдет селектор `body>div:first-child`

```css
body>div:first-child {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('body');
parent.firstElementChild.style.cssText = 'display:none';
```

```html
<body>
<div>Нужно скрыть</div>
<div>1234</div>
</body>
```

Не знаю будет это правильно , но на Jquery Можно скрыть примерно так попробовать

```
$('body').next().css({'display':'none'});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению не сработало :(

Comment: это сработает если элемент уже есть в разметке на момент выполнения скрипта, но не иначе

Answer (score 1):

удалить первый див элемент внутри body

```
$('body div:first').remove();
```